# Verilog always block statement

Tags: verilog

i just want to know the difference between this two statement

```
always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
       state <= next_state;
    end
```

AND:

```
always @(CLK)
    begin
     case(CLK)
        1'b1:
           state <= next_state;
        1'b0:
           state <= state;
    end
```

Is there a difference between both ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Not quite. `posedge` detects these transitions (from the LRM):

```
Table 43—Detecting posedge and negedge
To   0       1       x       z
From
0    No edge posedge posedge posedge
1    negedge No edge negedge negedge
x    negedge posedge No edge No edge
z    negedge posedge No edge No edge
```

So, 0->x is a `posedge`, for example. Your second example only detects cases where `CLK` ends up as 1, so misses 0->x and 0->z.

Answer (score 3):

The IEEE Std. 1364.1(E):2002 (IEC 624142(E):2005), the Verilog register transfer level synthesis standard, states in Sec. 5.1 that an always block without any `posedge`/`negedge` events in the sensitivity list is combinational logic. I.e. the signals in the event list are ignored and the block is synthesized as if an implicit expression list (`@(*)`, `@*`) was used. The following example is given in the standard ("Example 4" on page 14):

```
always @ (in)
  if (ena)
    out = in;
  else
    out = 1’b1;
// Supported, but simulation mismatch might occur.
// To assure the simulation will match the synthesized logic, add ena
// to the event list so the event list reads: always @ (in or ena)
```

(the comment is also copied from the standard document)

I.e. for a synthesis tool your second block is effectively:

```
always @*
    begin
     case(CLK)
        1'b1:
           state <= next_state;
        1'b0:
           state <= state;
    end
```

which is just a multiplexer with `CLK` as select input, `next_state` as active-1 input and the output (`state`) fed back as active-0 input. A smart synthesis tool might detect that this is identical to a d-type latch with `CLK` as enable-input and create a d-type latch instead of a combinational loop. Note that the synthesis tool is not required to detect this latch because the code explicitly assigns `state` in all branches (compare Sec. 5.3. of the standard).

Either way this is different from the d-type flip-flop your first code example would synthesize to. This is one of many cases where Verilog-code has different meaning in simulation and synthesis. Therefore it is important to (1) write synthesizeable Verilog code in a way that avoids this cases and (2) always run post-synthesis simulations of your design (even if you are also using formal verification!) to make sure you have successfully avoided this pitfalls.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about synthesis. Yes, they're clearly very different for synthesis, and a synthesiser might reject the second case, but their differences as "Verilog", defined by the LRM, is slight.

Comment: I'd also like to see a case where a synth actually turns all non posedge/negedge event controls into @* - this would make it impossible to synthesise latches.

Comment: @EML the following is a latch: always @* if (en) q <= d;

Comment: Yes, 'impossible' was the wrong word. But consider `always @(sel,a) if(sel) out <= a; else out <= b;`, which is a latch. The value of `b` is latched when `sel` falls; the latch output remains constant till `sel` rises. However, if you replace the event control with `@*`, you no longer have a latch, you have a mux. you can't in general mess with event controls; it removes latch functionality which may be required.

Comment: @EML: Have you tried synthesizing your code? *In synthesis this is a mux*. E.g. with Xilinx XST you get: "WARNING:HDLCompiler:91 ... Signal <b> missing in the sensitivity list is added for synthesis purposes. HDL and post-synthesis simulations may differ as a result." and the synthesis result: "Summary: inferred   1 Multiplexer(s)."

Comment: That's not my point. Synthesis is not relevant; the Verilog code describes a latch, not a mux. XST can't cope, it realises that what it has done may not correctly describe the intent of the circuit or the letter of the LRM, and so it issues a warning. This is a *Verilog* group. What XST does does not define Verilog and, in this case, is wrong. If the question had been "how do these two get implemented differently by a synthesiser", then fair enough, but the question concerned the difference between two bits of Verilog code.

Comment: Yes. What XST does does not define Verilog. The IEEE Verilog Standards do! There is one IEEE standard for simulation and one for synthesis. The behavior I describe is defined in the IEEE Verilog synthesis standard, as quoted above. XST implements this standard, as do many many other tools. There is a different behavior in simulation than in synthesis. But this does not make one a Verilog behavior and the other one a non-Verilog behavior. It only makes one a Verilog simulation behavior and the other a Verilog synthesis behavior.

Comment: The LRM defines Verilog, period. The synthesis standard simply defines a subset of Verilog that is suitable for synthesis and is expected to be supported across all synthesisers. It does not change the LRM semantics in any way, and cannot. The behaviour you describe changes the semantics of the Verilog description. The fact that a synthesiser turns my example code into a mux (which *I* pointed out, not you) demonstrates that the synthesiser has *incorrectly* synthesised the code; it does not demonstrate that the code *is* a mux. The code has the behaviour of a latch.

Comment: You repeated what I already wrote in my answer. All you did was replacing a "case" with an "if". And if you would have read what I wrote you would have understood that its not just "a synthesizer" but every one that works according to the synthesis *standard* document, that happens to define a different semantics than the LRM in some cases. Obviously you simply refuse to accept that IEEE Std. 1364.1(E):2002 exists, believe standardized behavior is "incorrect" and think what synthesis tools do is vendor specific magic that has nothing to do with a standardized behavior. Your religion, not mine.

Comment: Pointless, but you said "There is a different behavior in simulation than in synthesis. But this does not make one a Verilog behavior and the other one a non-Verilog behavior". The simulator must follow LRM semantics. If the synth behaves differently, the synth is wrong, period. It is not correct because of the existence of the synth standard. You could also argue that the author is "wrong", in that they have asked the synth to do something it cannot or should not do. It doesn't change the fact that only the LRM defines correct Verilog semantics. XST, and the synth standard, are not relevant.

Comment: The synth standard was intiated by OVI (the organization that also started the first Verilog standard in 1990), since 1998 its developed under a IEEE-SA PAR, became a IEEE final draft standard in 2002 and a full standard in 2005. It states clearly in the introduction that it describes "*the standard syntax and semantic of Verilog synthesis*" (that is a direct quote). But if you simply declare it *irrelevant and wrong* because you would prefer a different (simpler) reality, then surely it must be that way. I fully agree with you: Obviously there is no point in further arguing about this.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, those two circuits describe the same behavior in verilog, so I think there should be no difference.

However you should generally use the first style, as that is the one that is standard for writing synthesizable code, and most understandable by anyone else reading your code. The latter style, while describing the correct behavior, may confuse some synthesizers that don't expect to see clocks that are both sensitive to positive and negative edge.

Comment: i am getting difference behavior on my signal tap 2.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're referring to. If you are getting some unexpected behavior feel free to edit your question with real code and waveforms, or post a new question if you think it's not related.

Answer (score 1):

The two blocks are **VERY** different.

The top one gives you a flip-flop while the bottom one gives you a latch with a multiplexer with the CLK as the select signal.

The critical difference between the two blocks is that the top one is a synchronous block i.e. the *posedge clk* part while the bottom one is asynchronous with the CLK level, not edge.

Comment: The bottom block is not a latch/multiplexer, as it is not sensitive to the mux input (next_state). It only changes on posedge or negedge of the clock, making it similar to a dual-edge sensitive flop. However no action is taken on the negative edge transition, so I believe it is just the same as a posedge signal (ignoring x/z issues as pointed out by EML)

Comment: To add to Tim's comment, 'level' and 'edge' sensitivity is a misnomer. The term 'level' is used to distinguish posedge/negedege from everything else. event controls always detect *changes* in signals; posedge/negedge just (unnecessarily, in principle and, arguably, incorrectly) restrict the range of changes that will be detected.

Answer (score 1):

A verilog simulator *could* do left-hand sampling of `CLK`, effectively making the the `case(CLK)` version the same as a `negedge CLK` flop. Otherwise the simulator will treat it like a `posedge CLK` flop. It really depends how it is handled in the scheduler of specific simulator (or how a particular synthesizer will process it).

The most common codding styles all use the first condition. It is explicitly clear to the synthesizer and anyone reading the code that `state` is intended to be a flip-flop with a positive edge clocking trigger.

There is also a simulation performance differences. The `posedge CLK` performances 2 CPU operations every clock period, while the `case(CLK)` will perform 6 CPU operations every clock period. Granted in this example the differences is insignificance, but in large designs the poor coding used everywhere will add up to hours of simulation time wasted.